# Location in comment tag not being output

Tags: comments

I have this code and it should output the location (I have checked that it exists in Expression Engine comment admin) but it doesn't output the data. I have look everywhere for a solution but nothing is indicating why the location is not being output. (Using EE 2.6.0)

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" status="open" limit="20"}
                <article class="recipe-comment">
                    <div class="recipe-comment-author"><strong{location}</strong> Review by {name}</div>
                    {comment}

                    <p class="recipe-comment-post-date">Posted on {comment_date format="%j%S %F %Y"}</p>
                </article>
            {/exp:comment:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't close your `<strong>` element.  You need this:

```
<strong>{location}</strong>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It doesn't resolve the issue though

Comment: Hmm. You're sure that the members have data in the location field in the CP?

Comment: Definitely. Absolutley flummoxed.